# Как заменить обратные слеши на двойные обратные

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня переменная, в нее попадает вот такая запись

`E:\my\svpo\Settings\`

Как мне в ней заменить обратные одинарные слеши на двойные? Должно получится вот так

```
E:\\my\\svpo\\Settings\\
```

Пробовал использовать ReplaceSubstring но ничего у меня не получается, нуб я полный в JS. Подскажите решение.

Собственно весь код.

```
var FSO, WshShell, cur_dir, new_folder, new_file, list, index;

// Создаем объект WScript.Shell
WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
cur_dir = WshShell.CurrentDirectory;
FSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 

var new_file = FSO.OpenTextFile(""+cur_dir+"\\cur_dir.txt", 2, true); 
new_file.WriteLine(""+cur_dir+"\\");




WScript.Echo (cur_dir);
```

Comment: С помощью `.replace()` можно `\\ ` заменять на `\ `

Answer (score 5):

Обратные слэши используются для [экранирования](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) символов и для обозначения [классов](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-character-classes) символов, и должны быть экранированы сами собой и в строках, и в регулярных выражениях:

```js
var str = 'E:\\my\\svpo\\Settings\\';
console.log(str);

str = str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
console.log(str);
```

Двойной обратный слэш при записи `\\` в действительности является просто обратным слэшем `\`, а четверной `\\\\` - двойным `\\`.

Comment: Такой метод уже пробовал, не работает.